# Use pivot_longer on wide-like table in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I have some data that looks like this

```
color   value_morning   quality_morning value_evening   quality_evening value_night quality_night
red     10              good            9               good            10          good
blue    7               bad             8               great           10          great
green   7               bad             8               good            6           bad
```

and I am trying to use `pivot_longer()` (or any other `tidy` method) to transform it into:

```
color   value   time
red     10      morning
blue    7       morning
green   7       morning
red     9       evening
blue    8       evening
green   8       evening
red     10      night
blue    10      night
green   6       night
```

I don't need the `quality_` data, just the `value_` data.

I tried creating a vector that looked like `labels <- c("value_morning", "value_evening", "value_night")` and running `df %>% pivot_longer(cols = labels)` but that didn't work. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We remove the `quality` colums and then do the `pivot_longer`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df1 %>% 
   select(-starts_with('quality')) %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = -color, names_to = c(".value", "time"), 
          names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 3
  color time    value
  <chr> <chr>   <int>
1 red   morning    10
2 red   evening     9
3 red   night      10
4 blue  morning     7
5 blue  evening     8
6 blue  night      10
7 green morning     7
8 green evening     8
9 green night       6
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(color = c("red", "blue", "green"), value_morning = c(10L, 
7L, 7L), quality_morning = c("good", "bad", "bad"), value_evening = c(9L, 
8L, 8L), quality_evening = c("good", "great", "good"), value_night = c(10L, 
10L, 6L), quality_night = c("good", "great", "bad")),
 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: any advice for handling when my original column names have multiple underscores, such as `value_early_morning`? I tried editing the regex you provided but kept getting a "regex should define 2 groups" error.

Comment: @grapestory in that case, do `names_pattern = "^([^_]+)_(.*)"` i.e. match one or more characters that are not a `_` (`([^_]+)`) fro m the start of (`^`) of the column name, and this will be captured in group, then the `_` and the res of the characters